# How do I scale this image to fit my header?

Tags: html, css

My header only has a height of 108px

[This is how big my header is](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yRTwX.png)

But the image/logo I want to place is clearly bigger
[When I remove the height limit in my CSS, this is how it looks like](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HoIYf.png)

how do I rescale my image to fit my header? I'm  new to html and css and trying to learn to code, thank you in advance!

***this is my html and css***

```css
header.top {
  background - color: #157bea;
  margin: 10px,10px, 0px, 10px;
  height: 108px;
}

img.logowhite {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  object-fit: 100%;
}
```

```html
<header class = top>
  <div class = logowhite>
    <img src = images/logowhite.png>
  </div>
</header>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Set the `width` CSS attribute to `auto` value as follows and set the height with the `px` value.

On your CSS, your header has got the fixed height `108px` so it will be fine to define the height in pixel.

And currently, `img` tag is inside `.logwhite` selector so it is needed to replace `img.logowhite` to `.logowhite img`.

```
.logowhite img {
    width: auto;
    height: 108px;
}
```

Comment: Hello sir Derek, thank you for answering my query, but I did this to my code and I am still achieving the same result

Comment: I have updated my answer and for defining img style, pls use `.logowhite img { width: auto; height: 108px; }`

Comment: Hello sir Derek, this seems to have worked, thank you very much!!

Comment: Can you approve my answer if it works well with no issues?